# Assembly program with unsigned/signed division

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying write a simple Assembly program that divide 1000 by 5, but my program freezes the system.

The program is as follows,

```
include pcmac.inc   
.model Small
.586

.stack 100h

.data
const db 5

Main PROC
    _Begin  

    mov AX, 1000  
    idiv const  // Problem line

    _Exit 0 
Main ENDP
    End Main
```

The problem goes away if I use unsigned division `div` instead of signed division `idiv`.

Can anyone explain why?

The only condition I know for division is the dividend has to be double the size of divisor. Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` is a byte. When you do `IDIV byte_divisor` the quotient will be placed in `AL`, and has a range of -128 to 127. 1000 / 5 is 200, which isn't within the allowed range. If you use `DIV`, the range of the quotient is 0 to 255, which is why your example works in that case.

If you want to `IDIV` 1000 by 5 you should be using a 16-bit divisor instead. But you'll need to keep in mind that when using `IDIV r/m16`, what you're actually is dividing is the 32-bit doubleword made up of `DX` and `AX` (`DX` holding the most significant bits, and `AX` the least significant bits).

From Intel's manual:

```
IDIV r/m16    Signed divide DX:AX by r/m16, with result stored in AX ← Quotient, DX ← Remainder.

IF OperandSize = 16 (* Doubleword/word operation *)
THEN
    temp ← DX:AX / SRC; (* Signed division *)
    IF (temp > 7FFFH) or (temp < 8000H)
    (* If a positive result is greater than 7FFFH
    or a negative result is less than 8000H *)
    THEN
        #DE; (* Divide error *) 
    ELSE
        AX ← temp;
        DX ← DX:AX SignedModulus SRC;
```

So before `IDIV` you should create a signed doubleword in `DX:AX` from the value in `AX`. There's an instruction named `CWD` that does exactly that:

> The `CWD` instruction
>   copies the sign (bit 15) of the value in the `AX` register into every bit position in the `DX` register.

I.e.:

```
.data
const dw 5   ; now a word

.code
mov ax,1000
cwd          ; sign-extend ax into dx
idiv const
; quotient is in ax, remainder in dx
```